# Android Rect rotation

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, rect

```
public static void rotateRect(final int degrees, final int px, final int py, final Rect rect) {
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(degrees, px, py);
    matrix.mapRect(rectF);
    rect.set((int) rectF.left, (int) rectF.top, (int) rectF.right, (int) rectF.bottom);
}
```

I use this function to rotate a rect. But the result is a bigger rect !

this is the initial rect:
[image]

and afer I call

```
rotateRect(55, stickRect.centerX(), stickRect.centerY(), stickRect);
```

this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: `mapRect` docs say: "Apply this matrix to the src rectangle, and write the transformed rectangle into dst. This is accomplished by transforming the 4 corners of src, and then **setting dst to the bounds of those points**"

Comment: and how I am supposed to do that ? I am pretty newbie and I don't get it exactly

Comment: provide me some code sample please.

Comment: what problems do you have with `mapPoints(points)` method call?

Comment: `mapPoints(rectF.left, (int) rectF.top, (int) rectF.right, (int) rectF.bottom)`

this is what I have to call ?

Comment: have you read `mapPoints` documentation?

Comment: yes man, I read it. but I dnt get it how to use. how I get the transformet rect coordinates ? Because all mapPoints functions are  `void`

Comment: see my comment above: use `mapPoints(points)`

Comment: you mean this one: `public void mapPoints (float[] pts)` ?

and what parameter should I give ?

who has to be **float[] pts** ?

Comment: yes, there is only one method `mapPoints` that takes one parameter

Comment: again, docs say: "`public void mapPoints (float[] pts)` Parameters
pts The array [x0, y0, x1, y1, ...] of points to transform." what is unclear?

Comment: @pskink have you read the documentation of Rect ?   I can't use the array from mapPoints, which has 8 items (x0y0, x1y1, x2.....) to new Rect(xa, b, c, d).

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: I said that I can't use mapPoints to rotate a Rect.

Comment: ok lets start from the beginning: you have one Rect, you try to rotate it, then? what next?

Comment: and I try to rotate it like this

`Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setRotate(angle, centertX, centerY);
m.mapRect(Rect);`

and I expect to see the rect rotated by angle degrees. But what I have is just a bigger Rect, like in the images above

Comment: see [this](http://pasteboard.co/1jRNNqrf.png), does it make sense now?

Comment: yes! this is what I need

Comment: do you now know why green rect is bigger?

Comment: ooo, and I need the coordinates of the new rotated red rect. how I get them ?

Comment: by using **mapPoints**

Comment: but mapPoints return 8 coordintates... x0,y0, x1,y1, x2,y2..... etc..... 
and when I create a new rect I can use only four. Rect (left top, right bottom). This is uncler for me. How to use those coordinates from map points to create a rotated Rect

Comment: what do you need new rect for? you have 4 rotated points: just draw them

Comment: I need to check a collison between another Rect and this rotated rect.  
This is very unclear. How to draw the rotated Rect ? Because it  continue to draw me the big red rect instead of the rotated green one !

Comment: you have 4 points, then use a `Path#moveTo` / `Path#lineTo` / `Path.close`

Comment: Can you post it like an answer ? A sample ? because like this, it confuses me